# Dúvida sobre funções no php

Tags: php, string, funções

Uma função só funciona se chamarmos ela em algum arquivo ou ela funcionará de qualquer forma? Por exemplo, para passar o valor de uma variável para outra, no arquivo do processamento, eu sei que devo chamar a função para dar valor à variável. Mas quando quero apenas passar um valor de uma string para outra string, por exemplo:

```
public function conta_teste_profissional($codigo){
    $conexao = Database::getConnection();
    $busca = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE cod_usuario_profissional = $codigo;";
    $resultado = $conexao->query($busca);
    $retorno = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $tamanho = count($retorno);
    return $tamanho;
}
```

.

Eu preciso chamá-la em algum outro arquivo ou essa função funcionará automaticamente?

Comment: Tenta ser mais específica na sua dúvida...

Comment: A pergunta não está muito clara para mim, para ser executada, uma função precisa ser chamada idependentemente do arquivo (desde que o mesmo tenha sido carregado). O que seria _"funcionará de qualquer forma"_?

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta não está muito clara, mas se a dúvida é "funções são invocadas automaticamente" a resposta é não. Você deve chamar a função em cada parte do seu código que deseje utilizá-la. Tomando seu exemplo como base

```
public function conta_teste_profissional($codigo){
    $conexao = Database::getConnection();
    $busca = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE cod_usuario_profissional = $codigo;";
    $resultado = $conexao->query($busca);
    $retorno = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $tamanho = count($retorno);
    return $tamanho;
}
```

O bloco acima será responsável apenas por declarar a função, caso queira usar, você deve chamá-la no local que seja adequado a você.  Exemplo:

```
conta_teste_profissional(4)
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Muito bom saber disso, obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

As funções, mesmo estando declaradas, não são invocadas/iniciadas automaticamente. Você deve chamar a função na parte do seu código em que você precisa da mesma.

Usando seu código como exemplo:

```
public function conta_teste_profissional($codigo){
    $conexao = Database::getConnection();
    $busca = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE cod_usuario_profissional = $codigo;";
    $resultado = $conexao->query($busca);
    $retorno = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $tamanho = count($retorno);
    return $tamanho;
}
```

A função só seria executada se você chamasse a mesma desta forma:

```
conta_teste_profissional(10); //Exemplo
```

Você pode, também, chamar uma função declarada em outro arquivo PHP dando um include no arquivo no qual a mesma está declarada.

Aqui está o manual sobre **INCLUDE**: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php